Low budget movie about four female friends, came on BET years ago
The movie is directed by a woman with short hair. 
It's about four female friends from college

one was raped and got pregnant in college and now she is a lawyer and lonely 
another is a lesbian and in love with her friend 
another is a slut and slept with her friend's fiancé and they find out all the secrets at the wedding. 

One of the actresses favors Jill Marie Jones. The lesbian in the movie is a successful body trainer to Hollywood stars. 
They get together for a weekend to be bridesmaids in one of the friends' wedding. 

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What does "years ago" mean? What is BET? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

BET=The Black Entertainment Television channel.

You're looking for Truth Hall from 2008. From Rotten Tomatoes:

Secrets come out and hearts get broken when old friends reunite for a wedding in this bold urban dramedy. Though they were as close as sisters in college, the five women have since parted ways; when they resurface for the celebration, they'll each bring a little bit of their own drama to the table.

All the details you mentioned are there. The movie is about to be remade. Here's the trailer:



